# cx_Freeze fails to freeze script due to mpl_toolkits

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, cx-freeze

I am trying to freeze this [program](https://github.com/BooleanDesign/Electrical-Field-Toolkit/blob/master/Electrical%20Field%20API/Electric%20Field%20API.py) Using the following setup script:

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
import os

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("Electric Field API.py", base=base, icon=os.getcwd()+"\\bin\\EFAPIicon.ico")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "Electric Field API",
    options = {"build_exe": {'includes': ['numpy.core._methods','numpy.lib.format','tkFileDialog','FileDialog'], 'packages': ["matplotlib",'Tkinter','FileDialog','tkFileDialog'], "include_files":[os.getcwd()+"\\bin\\EFAPIicon.ico"]}},
    version = "1.3",
    description = "Electric Field Visualization",
    executables = executables
    )
```

Unfortunately, when running this, I receive the following error: [image]

When these imports are listed in the setup.py file, I receive the following error from powershell:
[image]

If anyone has a way to solve this issue, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Neither `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d`, nor `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1` are listed in the `"packages"`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Adding either of the induces the error from the powershell shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently mpl_toolkits is a namespace package (no '**init**'), hence it has to be treated differently. ( I read a little about this on bitbucket(thanks D. Reaver)

Try adding the following to your build_exe in the options:

'namespace_packages': ['mpl_toolkits']